# Cómo añadir un item a un DropDownList en razor, pero con value 0?

Tags: mvc, razor, dropdownlist

He querido agregar a mi lista un item que diga "seleccione", y si lo logro, pero ocupo que ese item tome el `value=0`, no sé si haya una manera de hacerlo desde el razor.

Lo que tengo es el siguente código y si pone el item "Seleccione Rol", pero con value `null`.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Roles", new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles2, "IdRol", "NombreRol"),"Seleccione Rol")
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes agregar un elemento de está forma`Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem{Text="Seleccionar", Value="0",Selected=true})` la propiedad `Selected=true` dejara el item seleccionado por defecto. Saludos